# Expectation and variance of matrix valued random variable

Tags: probability, matrices, random-variables, expectation, variance

Suppose I have a discrete matrix-valued random variable $X$, that is, I have defined a set of fixed matrices $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$, and the random variable $X = Y_i$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. Is there any coherent theory for investigating the expectation and variance of this r.v. $X$?

It seems that a reasonable(?) definition of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is

\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i}^n Y_i
\end{align*}

which produces a matrix as the expectation. But I have no idea how the variance should be interpreted. Should the usual definition be used?

\begin{align*}
Var(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2
\end{align*}

What does the squared even mean in this case?

Searching produces a lot of literature of the statistics of random matrices whose individual entries are random variables, not I was not able to find anything on the situation outlined above. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "random matrices whose individual entries are random variables" and "matrix-valued random variable" are the same thing

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving you a quick answer because I'm lazy, but hope this helps you!

Treat the $m \times n$ matrix as a big vector of dimensions $mn$. So, treat, $X$  as a random vector $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{mn}$. Now, look the this wiki page: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable

In short, $E(X)$ will be a matrix of same dimensions so that $E(X)_{ij}:=E(X_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, following the wiki page, the covaraince of your random variable will be a $mn \times mn$ dimensional matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The variance is defined in terms of the transpose, i.e. say $X$ is a real-valued random variable in matrix form then its variance is given by
$$ \mathrm{Var} (X) = \mathbb{E} \left[ (X - \mathbb{E}[X])(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^\top\right].$$
In your case this would results in
$$\mathrm{Var} (X) = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \left(X_k- \mathbb{E}[X] \right)\left(X_k - \mathbb{E}[X] \right)^\top$$
 Hope this helps you.